# How to force user implement __weak functions

Tags: c, weak

I'm writing a library and have some `__weak` functions which need to be overwritten by the programmers. I want to make sure they do so, so I did this:

```
__weak void checkButtons(){
    #warning "Implement this"
}
```

And put the prototype in the header:

```
__weak void checkButtons();
```

And implement it in another file:

```
void checkButtons(){
    //Some codes here
}
```

By the way, the problem is that in compile time, the compiler shows the `#warning` message.

> compiling library.c...
>
> library.c(8): warning:  #1215-D: #warning directive: message "Implement this"
>
> #warning message "Implement this"
>
> library.c: 1 warning, 0 errors

I think if a `__weak` function is overridden, the main function should not be compiled, should be?

I don't know why this happens. Any other idea to force the user?

Comment: Don't use `weak`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> the main function should not be compiled, should be?

Everything is compiled. Weak functions are compiled, normal functions are compiled. The linker *when linking* the program *chooses* (the compiled) normal version of the symbol over the (also compiled) weak version of the symbol. Linking happens after compilation.

> why this happens.

You have written a `#warning` in your code and it's going to be visible and processed by the compiler anyway, irrelevant if the function is used or not. `#warning`s are interpreted by the preprocessor, *before* compilation.

> How to force user implement __weak functions

First, do not use `weak` in header file. It would make **all** function **definitions** weak that see this declaration.

```
// header
void checkButtons();
```

Secondly, if you want to force user to define the function, then don't use `weak` and don't define the function. Weak symbols are used when you **want** to provide a default definition for the function, if you don't want to do it then don't use it. Without function definition, user will receive a "undefined reference"-kind-of error message from the linker.

> I'm writing a library and have some functions which need to be overwritten by the programmers

Yet better and normal way would be for your library to take function pointers that point to the functions implemented by the user of your library. Such design is "better" - allows code reuse, easier unit-testing and saves a lot of refactoring in case of later changes.

Comment: What does "It would make all function definitions weak that see this declaration." mean?

Comment: And `checkButtons()` is a function which I need to remind the user to implement. I don't' call it anywhere in my library. How can my library take the function pointer? What do you mean?

Comment: `weak void checkButtons(); void checkButtons()  { something; }` is __the same__ as `weak  void checkButtons() { something ; }`. A weak function declaration makes following function definitions all weak.

Comment: `I don't' call it anywhere in my library` I do not understand. Then it's pointless to implement it at all. `How can my library take the function pointer?` Functions pointers are basic C concepts. Refer to a good C book, see `qsort` or `atexit` for standard examples, also `scandir`. From top of my head: [gpiod with poll event callback](https://github.com/brgl/libgpiod/blob/master/include/gpiod.h#L358) as an example.

Comment: It's not that useless, I want to remind the user to implement it.

Comment: @MohammadKholghi Read the answer again, carefully: Your user will get the reminder from the linker. If the user does not implement the function, the linker will complain heavily and refuse to build the executable.